# Draw non-orthogonal axis in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to draw a Minkowski diagram.
It includes two different axis, one for each system, they are, however, not all orthogonal. Is there a way to plot a pair of axis for one system non-orthogonal?

Comment: Also see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1664

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an example using [AxisArtist](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/axisartist.html) and [GridHelperCurveLinear](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/axisartist.html#gridhelper), which is modified from [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_curvelinear_grid.html).

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  mpl_toolkits.axisartist.grid_helper_curvelinear import GridHelperCurveLinear
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist import Subplot

def curvelinear_test1(fig):
    def tr(x, y):
        x, y = np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y)
        return .8*x+.2*y, .2*x + .8*y
    def inv_tr(x,y):
        x, y = np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y)
        return 1.333*x + -.333*y, -.333*x + 1.333*y

    grid_helper = GridHelperCurveLinear((tr, inv_tr))
    ax1 = Subplot(fig, 1, 1, 1, grid_helper=grid_helper)
    fig.add_subplot(ax1)

    xx, yy = tr([3, 6], [5.0, 10.])
    ax1.plot(xx, yy)

    ax1.set_aspect(1.)
    ax1.set_xlim(-10, 10.)
    ax1.set_ylim(-10, 10.)

    ax1.axis["t"]=ax1.new_floating_axis(0, 0.)
    ax1.axis["t2"]=ax1.new_floating_axis(1, 0.)
    ax1.grid(True)

fig = plt.figure()
curvelinear_test1(fig)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Works great! It is very nice you took the time to answer the question so nicely! Thanks!

Comment: @andi: Glad it worked for you.  I have, btw, edited this.  What I had before was mathematically correct, but probably not matching the physics you wanted, since I had x and y switched in the transformed axes.  Before I had `x'=.2x+.8y`, and now I have `x'=.8x+.2y`; that is, relative velocity adds a little time into space, but it doesn't swap them.

Comment: ;) I managed to derive it from the example. So it worked quite quickly. Thanks for also adding it to the post. Makes it even more valuable!