# Draw 3D non-orthogonal coordinates

Tags: matplotlib, plot, gnuplot, wolfram-mathematica

There is already a post asking how to draw non-orthogonal axis in a 2D coordinate system in matplotlib. 
[Draw non-orthogonal axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581073/draw-non-orthogonal-axis-in-matplotlib)
I wonder how to draw such axis in a 3D case? Say z-axis is perpendicular to x-y plane while x and y axes are not orthogonal. For example, how to draw scattered 3D plot for (1,2,0) and (3,2,0) in a curvilinear system? Not restricted in using matplotlib. Thanks!

Comment: This post also considers 2D plot: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128427/how-to-create-a-plot-with-inclined-axes

Comment: if you want a mathematica solution you should go ask on that site. Generically asking for solutions in 5 different languages is really not appropriate here btw.

Comment: There is no need to be restricted in Mathematica. Any solution in one of these languages listed is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in Matlab. It works for non-orthogonal axes, but not for the full general case of curvilinear coordinates. You control the axes with the matrix `A`. It is currently set to make the x-axis 45 degrees from the y. `A = eye(3)` would make them orthogonal again.

The script opens two plots. The first is a normal, orthogonal 3d plot. The second respects the coordinate transform (non-ortho axes). To check it, look at the second plot from above, you should see the circle has become an oval.

```
close all
clear

fx = @(t) t.^2 .* cos(2*t);
fy = @(t) t.^2 .* sin(2*t);
fz = @(t)  t;
t = linspace(0,6*pi,400);

figure
plot3(fx(t), fy(t), fz(t));
grid on

xTicks = get(gca, 'XTick');
yTicks = get(gca, 'YTick');
zTicks = get(gca, 'ZTick');

% coordinate transform: x = Aq
A = [sqrt(2)/2 sqrt(2)/2 0
    0 1 0
    0 0 1];
%A = eye(3);

figure
hold on

% draw the function
Q = [fx(t); fy(t); fz(t)];
X = A*Q;
plot3(X(1,:), X(2,:), X(3,:))

% draw x grid lines
x = [xTicks
    xTicks
    xTicks];
y = repmat([min(yTicks); max(yTicks); max(yTicks) ], 1, length(xTicks));
z = repmat([min(zTicks); min(zTicks); max(zTicks) ], 1, length(xTicks));
X = A*[x(:)'; y(:)'; z(:)'];
line(reshape(X(1,:), 3, []),...
    reshape(X(2,:), 3, []),...
    reshape(X(3,:), 3, []), 'color', [.8 .8 .8]);

% draw y grid lines
y = [yTicks
    yTicks
    yTicks];
x = repmat([min(xTicks); max(xTicks); max(xTicks) ], 1, length(yTicks));
z = repmat([min(zTicks); min(zTicks); max(zTicks) ], 1, length(yTicks));
X = A*[x(:)'; y(:)'; z(:)'];
line(reshape(X(1,:), 3, []),...
    reshape(X(2,:), 3, []),...
    reshape(X(3,:), 3, []), 'color', [.8 .8 .8]);

% draw z grid lines
z = [zTicks
    zTicks
    zTicks];
x = repmat([min(xTicks); max(xTicks); max(xTicks) ], 1, length(zTicks));
y = repmat([max(yTicks); max(yTicks); min(yTicks) ], 1, length(zTicks));
X = A*[x(:)'; y(:)'; z(:)'];
line(reshape(X(1,:), 3, []),...
    reshape(X(2,:), 3, []),...
    reshape(X(3,:), 3, []), 'color', [.8 .8 .8]);

% draw grid planes
q{1} = [xTicks(1) xTicks(1) xTicks(end) xTicks(end)
    yTicks(1) yTicks(end) yTicks(end) yTicks(1)
    zTicks(1) zTicks(1) zTicks(1) zTicks(1)];
q{2} = [xTicks(end) xTicks(end) xTicks(end) xTicks(end)
    yTicks(1) yTicks(1) yTicks(end) yTicks(end)
    zTicks(1) zTicks(end) zTicks(end) zTicks(1)];
q{3} = [xTicks(1) xTicks(1) xTicks(end) xTicks(end)
    yTicks(end) yTicks(end) yTicks(end) yTicks(end)
    zTicks(1) zTicks(end) zTicks(end) zTicks(1)];
for i = 1:3
    x = A*q{i};
    fill3(x(1,:), x(2,:), x(3,:), [1 1 1]);
end

% cleanup and set view
axis off
view(-35, 30)
```

The basic idea is that we need to manually draw each element of the plot (axes, grid, etc.) respecting the coordinate transform. It is painful, but can work.